# What is the best, easiest and most automated way to document a Salesforce org?

Tags: documentation

As the title suggests, what is the easiest way to document a Salesforce environment, in particular Apex Code and Flows. I've been looking at [ApexDoc](https://github.com/salesforcefoundation/apexdoc), but this has not been maintained for the last few years, so I am concerned there maybe challenges with using this an newer Apex functionality - it also appears this does not document flows.

Ideally I am looking for a tool that I can add into a build pipeline that documents all flows, and Apex methods, including inputs and outputs. This will then allow me to create a catalogue of 'services' that are then reusable by my developers as we build more and more customisation.

Answer (score 2):

We use [SfApexDoc](https://gitlab.com/StevenWCox/sfapexdoc), a variant of the standard ApexDoc documentation generator, which was recommended by Scott Wells, the author of [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/) (the IDE we use), to generate our "Public API documentation" directly from our Apex code (selected global classes). Whilst this also hasn't been updated in GitLab for years, it works fine for us since we focus on the API aspects (i.e. global interfaces, classes, methods, properties and attributes) which haven't really changed in later platform releases.

As for flows, doing an internet search shows you that there's no OOTB documentation generator for these at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Phil - I was drawing a blank as well when searching for something to document flows. I'd wondered if there were any commercial products that I was not aware of.

Comment: I also use SfApexDoc, but have recently used [this](https://github.com/cesarParra/apexdocs) that works well too but generates markdown files for Jekyll and Docsify sites.